# How do I handle errorChannel events in a integration test for Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I've an integration test that makes use of Spring Integration.

Now I noticed that if there is an error in a message router, the test passes happily. And I don't want it. So I know that error that happen in routers and other components, [they will be put in errorChannel by default](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler). Is there a way to quickly make a test fail in case errors are thrown and is there a way I can make this work in asynchronous situations?

Answer (score 3):

The default `error-channel` is pub/sub. If you are using a custom error channel, make it pub-sub and have your test subscribe another handler (`channel.subscribe(new MessageHander() {...}`).

Throw an exception in the handler (or execute a Junit `fail()`).

If the entry to the flow is a `<gateway/>`, this will work in both sync and async cases.